# Add description of field to FBL5N header

Tags: abap

I need to display the description of the field "KNB1-CESSION_KZ" in transaction FBL5N. 
For that I made an extension in structure `FILITEXTS_AR` with the desired Field `CESSION_KZ` and made a foreign key to the table `TCESSION` as descriped in KBA 363290.

I can now add the field to the header. But if I choose `TEXT` on the texttype nothing appears. It only works with `VALUE`.

[image]
[image]
[image]
Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you have defined your screen field (check the attributes in the dynpro) with an invalid type (numeric?) or length, so the chosen value cannot be transferred to the screen. Or maybe it's a SAP bug. Did you check SAP notes?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I used the correct type

Comment: Please show the technical attributes of the screen field and structure component.

Comment: I added the screenshots above

Comment: I was asking more about the screen field "Textart", but anyway I could find the name of the screen, SAPLGRWR 0150 (SAP ERP), so I could investigate a little further. If you click the line "TEXT Kurztext" of the listbox then you should see "TEXT Kurztext" in the input field immediately. Technically speaking, I don't understand why the initial value remains (" Wert"). Or is its value reset to " Wert" after you press `Enter`?

Comment: But I think you should open a ticket at SAP to get assistance. PS: by the way, there's the KBA [2254669](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2254669) which describes the process to define the variables (maybe it could help).

Comment: If I set to TEXT nothing appears. It's just empty. So my assumption is that there is just no link to the text table. I tried do do that with foreign key, but it didn't work

Comment: KBA 2254669 just shows me the process how to define that. But in my case I add a totally new Variable. It didn't even exists before. (By appending the structure descriped in KBA 363290)

Comment: Probably post your solution as an answer and yes, you should start a ticket to investigate if it is a bug

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a customer-side enhancement that did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the programm to find out how other texts are loaded and came across the include "LFILITEXTSF01". I made the following enhancement at the end of the form "GET_TEXT" and it worked.

[image]